# why my python program is giving wrong output?

Tags: python-3.x

I have below program

```
def remove_duplicates(A):
    result = []
    seen = set()
    for num in A:
        if num not in seen:
            result.append(num)
            seen.add(num)
    return result

N = int(input("Enter the size of the arrays: "))
A = list(map(int, input("Enter the elements of array A: ").split()))
B = list(map(int, input("Enter the elements of array B: ").split()))

# Create a new array to store the updated numbers
updated_A = [A[B[i]] + A[i] for i in range(N)]

# Remove duplicates from the updated array
result = remove_duplicates(updated_A)

# Print the resulting numbers
print("Numbers after removing duplicates:", end=" ")
for num in result:
    print(num, end=" ")
```

And, below is the problem statement

```
given an array A of integers of size N and a second array B having shuffled index numbers of the same size. you must match the index number for each number and add that number present on that index to the current number. For the ith index element of array A, add the number having index B[i] in array A. Print the numbers after removing the numbers that occur more than once for all elements of A
```

below is the sample input

```
N = 5
A = 1 5 4 7 8
B = 1 2 0 4 3
```

The expected output is `6 9 5`, but I am getting `6 9 5 15`

Please suggest

Comment: Have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program?

Comment: yes, since I didn't find the root cause so looking for help

Comment: I recommend you add printouts of *all* variable, directly after you assign to them. Is `A` what you expect directly after input? Is `updated_A`? Is `result`, `seen` and `num` in the `remove_duplicates` function? Even when you print them out inside the loop?

Comment: I also recommend you take some time to do some research on [*sets*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), since it can simplify creating a list of unique values without duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what would be in `updated_A` in your example

```py
N = 5
A = 1 5 4 7 8
B = 1 2 0 4 3
```

```py
updated_A = [A[B[i]] + A[i] for i in range(N)]
```

If you execute the list comprehension, you would get an array of sums of pairs:

```py
updated_A = [(5 + 1), (4 + 5), (1 + 4), (8 + 7), (7 + 8)]
```

Therefore

```py
updated_A = [6, 9, 5, 15, 15]
```

So the result of `remove_duplicates` that you are getting is indeed correct.

Answer (score 2):

As @Dima mentioned your `updated_A` list has the following numbers `[6, 9, 5, 15, 15]`

If you want to remove the duplicates (remove both 15) and get the result `6 9 5` you could try this:

```
from collections import Counter

def remove_duplicates(A):
    result ={key for (key,value) in Counter(A).items() if value==1}
    return result
```

> Python's counter() function is a built-in tool that enables developers
> to perform quick and efficient counting operations. It operates on
> iterables, including strings, lists, and dictionaries. The function
> creates a dictionary that maps each element in the iterable to its
> count or frequency in the collection.
> https://favtutor.com/blogs/python-counter